# $.get() works in IE but not FF

Tags: jquery

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this code? It works fine in IE8 but not in FF3.

```
$.get("http://google.com/", function(data) { alert(data); });
```

It shows me the alert window but it's empty.

Comment: Stating the obvious, you should check the value of `data` with Firebug, and see if it actually has anything in it.

Comment: Or just echo it out and see if there's any differences in IE/FF

Comment: I think it is because you can't receive something on a different site to prevent cross-side scripting - but I'm not sure :/ fun it works in IE, though.

Comment: I think lasseespheholt is correct.

Comment: @David W - Since no one else has asked, what is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, apperantly IE settings were changed, I reset it and it's not working on IE either. Irony of this question is that I wanted to get the code to work on both browsers and now it's not working on none of them. Gotta find a new solution...

Comment: @Ender I wanted to use this ajax request to get data from victim's mailbox since they (usually) have cookies installed on their browsers and are logged in. Not exactly this, but something similar.

Comment: "victim" is a funny term

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it has to do with the cross domain AJAX restrictions between the two browsers.  FireFox is more strict (secure) when it comes to AJAX.  Your code violates FireFox's ["Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)"

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Same Origin Policy isn't a Firefox-only feature, all modern browsers have this.  IE8's Same Origin Policy is the same as Firefox's, unless you disable it for a specific "Security Zone".

Comment: True, I guess I should have been a little more specific.  I believe its much harder to set Firefox to allow Access Across Domains which requires a proxy to be set up.  This is what I meant when I said it was more secure, Internet Explorer all you have to do is check the box without necessarily knowing what it is

Answer (score 7):

That code shouldn't work in Firefox *or* IE, due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Chances are, you've set your security settings for the site's zone to be able to access data across domains:

[image]

To change this behaviour (and you probably should), go to Internet Settings -> Security -> Choose the zone for the current site -> Choose Custom level...

Answer (score 3):

Please read the documentation for $.get() (or really any other jQuery AJAX call).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

It specifies the following lower down on the page: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

This is likely the source of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use AJAX to send a request to a different domain.

In IE, you apparently enabled this option.

## This is a *bad* security hole.

### You should re-disable it immediately

Go to Internet Options, Security, Custom Level, Miscellaneous, and disable Access Data Sources across Domains.

Comment: Lol that font just looks dangerous

Comment: Quite, I actually went to check MY settings after reading that!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesn't allowed cross site requests like that, for security purposes -- I'm surprised it works in IE. It should work from your own domain, though.